# My whitelist does not allow whistelisted site

Tags: iptables, whitelist

here is my whitelist allowing wikipedia and rejecting all other sites. Unfortunately this script does not work : I cannot connect to wikipedia. Why ?
Thank you

## Allow incoming traffic from established connections.

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

## Allow incoming connections from wikipedia

iptables -A INPUT -s 78.109.84.114 -j ACCEPT

## Allow outcoming connections from wikipedia

iptables -A OUTPUT -s 78.109.84.114 -j ACCEPT

## Drop other incoming connections.

iptables -P INPUT DROP

## Drop any transfer of traffic.

iptables -P FORWARD DROP

Answer (score 0):

I think i got your Problem.

Try using iptables -A OUTPUT -d 78.109.84.114 -j ACCEPT instead of
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 78.109.84.114 -j ACCEPT

And if you want to work with the state module then use:
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -d 78.109.84.114 -j ACCEPT

The Problem is, that you create a rule, that says that Traffic that goes into the OUTPUT Chain with the Source Adress 78.109.84.114 is allowed. But what you want is a rule that allows Traffic to Wikipedia outgoing not from Wikipedia.